# Determine truth value of ∃x P(x , y) when P(x,y) is the proposition $x^2 = y$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Although this may be a simple question but I'm forgetting if this would be a false statement.

> So let $P(x,y)$ be the proposition $x^2 = y$, where $x$ and $y$ are integers.
>   What would the truth value be in $∃ \ x; \ P(6, x)$?

Since $P$ is $(x,y)$, does this mean the statement would be $(6,6)$? Or does it restructure to $(y,x)$ which would then be $(6, 36)$?

Thanks for any replies.

Comment: Please, not be mistaken by the different places of the variable $x$ ... it is only a place-holder. In words, $∃x P(6, x)$ means : "there is some number $x$ such that $6^2=x$" and yu have to find its truth-value.

Comment: @Mauro Hmm I haven't read it like that before, would that be true then?

Comment: Yes, of course; $6^2=36$ and thus it is true that "there is an $x$ such that  $6^2=x$".

Comment: @Mauro Ahh I see, so the opposite ∃xP(x,6), be done in the same way and result in true?

Comment: Not exactly ... if we speak of *integers*, then $x^2=6$ has no solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given

> $P(x,y)$ be the proposition $x^2 = y$, where $x$ and $y$ are integers

$$$$
This infers that $P(y,x)$ be the proposition $y^2 = x$, where $y$ and $x$ are integers.

$$$$

**The Question**

$$∃ \ x; \ P(6, x)$$
This means: There exists an $x$ where $6^2 = x$.

$$6^2 = 36$$ and since 36 (along with 6) is an integer, this means that the statement $∃ \ x; \ P(6, x)$ is **true**.

In other words: It is **true** that there exists an integer equal to $6^2$

Comment: And if you want extra examples: $∃ \ x; \ P(x, 6)$ is false (since the root of 6 isn't an integer. $∃ \ x; \ P(\sqrt{2}, x)$ is false (because even though $(\sqrt{2})^{2}$ is an integer, $\sqrt{2}$ isn't an integer.) (It is specified that both arguments have to be integers). And $∃ \ x; \ P(3, 4)$ is false because $3^2 \neq 4$